# How to power bulbs expecting 24V AC from a car's "cigarrete" socket?

Tags: automotive, 24v, uv, dc-ac

I'm turning the trunk of my car into a UV-sanitizer chamber -- so that, by the time I return from the supermarket, the bags and the packages handled by strangers there are sterile.

To this end I lined the trunk with reflective film and purchased 8 little [UVC bulbs](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01EP28OKQ/), which I now need to power.

The bulbs need 18-24V *alternating current* and are said to use about 3Watts each. The socket is (said to be) E17, and I plan to use a wire from a [decoration garland](https://smile.amazon.com/Monkeydg-String-Lights-Outdoor-Voltage/dp/B07MCMZF3N/).

All of the DC-to-AC inverters I can find produce 110V AC, not 24VAC... There are also 110V-to-24V AC transformers, but I'd hate to resort to the cludge of using two different conversions.

Do the 12VDC-to-24VAC inverters *exist*, and how do I find one? Do I need ballast for these bulbs -- and how do I add it for all of them at once?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Penetration of UVC is so low into things like paper, food, etc that they will not be sanitized. UVC works on things that are transparent to UVC (water, air) or on completely nonpermiable surfaces like polished metal or glass.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @user1850479 -- I still expect it to be useful on store plastic bags, milk-bottles, and juice-cartons. With many little bulbs all around, there should be very few places in the "shadows" -- and it will have at least 10 minutes of the car-ride to work (usually -- longer).

Comment: Are you sure it won't work on DC? Worst case scenario is a 12V to 120V inverter and a 24V transformer. Otherwise, if it can run on DC, maybe you can just convert 12V to 24V. I hope you do not start a fire in your trunk. You may want to add a thermal detection or thermal cutoff to your system s that the lights turn off if the trunk gets too hot.

Comment: That's an idea, @mkeith -- and, no, I do not know the answer. I suppose, I can test with a computer's power-supply, eh? Also, I'm not sure, if ballast is required for these. Is fire really a danger, when converting such voltages?

Comment: @MikhailT. Have you done your diligence on these devices? (DC operation usually requires a specialized bulb that permits a pre-heat phase prior to arcing between the cathode and anode.) You'll want AC operation for these, I believe. Lots of reasons. Some of them related to gas transport and accumulation and banding issues. And yes, you will need to still account for reaching the strike voltage, which requires the use of an inductor for the ballast.

Comment: @MikhailT. It's also likely these are soft glass devices (they look like it to me.) Not the more efficient quartz "L" type enclosures which include titanium to block shorter wavelengths that can produce ozone. DNA is sensitive at about 260nm, but low pressure devices (.006 torr, likely) only emit lines. Medium pressure devices emit a much broader collision spectrum (due to the higher pressure and far more ground-state atoms that absorb the 253.7nm line.) Those are often used for more aggressive sterilization. The point here is you should "study up" a little, first. Some due diligence is good.

Comment: @jonk, sorry, I don't understand -- are you saying, these might not be properly sterilizing, or that there is some other danger (like fire)? What diligence is due?

Comment: your idea can actually make you sick ... you will be lulled into a false sense of security by thinking that the system actually killed most of the bacteria .... that does not even address possible problems with exposing food to UV radiation

Comment: @MikhailT. Regarding a schematic, I think you may first need to understand how to "start" these bulbs. I don't think it will be quite as simple as you imagine. In general, though, there's much more to understand before proceeding regarding their use. The owner of [DIY Physics site](http://www.diyphysics.com/) has an excellent book [Exploring Quantum Physics through Hands-on Projects](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1118140664) which provides some basic understanding of the Crookes and Faraday dark spaces vs gas pressure and some wonderful experiments. "Due diligence" means "get informed first."

Comment: @MikhailT. It requires work to gain a sufficiently comprehensive understanding. It's not just about "how to make one work." You should read (study up) on the current state of knowledge about applying these kinds of devices for the purposes you intend. There will be lots of research available. Then, I'd recommend contacting a scientist or two (you'll know who, from the research you read.) And then experiment ***a lot*** before committing to any actual usage. Your eye corneas are only the first thing I worry about. But not the only. Design isn't about "on/off." There's more to it.

Comment: Start your "due dilligence" by watching some of BigClive's videos about Germicidal UV lamps here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2T39BHvrHZ0 He uses a lamp which runs on 240 V AC. There are so called "inverters" which turn 12 V DC from a car into 240 V AC. As commented, there are other issues regarding using UV. Keeping distance, avoiding crowds and washing hands is generally considered much more effective than UV-ing your groceries. Consider just wiping the groceries with a desinfecting (alcohol based) spray.

Comment: Note that the product contains this text:
HQRP UV Germicidal Bulb replaces ONLY Philips Sonicare Part # 423502504291 & 423509004221 and is compatible ONLY with the models mentioned in the product description.

Comment: In order to keep this question from going stale when that amazon link stops working, would it be reasonable to put a screen cap image of the product in the original question? Or maybe should the question be closed?

Comment: @jonk, jsotola, Bumpelrekkie please, keep stay on the topic of electricity and electrical engineering. Biology and quantum mechanics aren't it...

Comment: Following @mkeith's suggestion, I tested one of the bulbs with an old laptop adapter -- producing 19V DC. The bulb worked (I wore my ski-mask to protect the eyes), so I got the 12-to-24 DC transformer and tried three of them together in the car... All three flickered briefly and then burned out. Did I get a bad batch, or was it my mistake -- and I should've used a lower DC voltage than the maximum AC-rating?